# How to determine if a Shopify order was placed via the Amazon channel?

Tags: shopify, amazonsellercentral

I am querying the Shopify API for a specific order and I would like to know how to determine if the order was placed in our Amazon Seller channel and sent to Shopify as it is described in Shopify's documentation: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/amazon-sales-channel/processing-orders. On the section "Fulfilling Orders" of that page it reads:

> All new orders placed through Amazon appear in your orders list and
>   are marked as **Amazon**.

A real JSON response from the Order API looks like this: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order#show

I could not find any indication that the order might come via Amazon. I did find the fulfillment service (just a simple Ctrl F "amazon") but that is a different thing.

Being a Shopify Plus customer we asked their Guru Support team how they implement the *"marked as Amazon"* part and the response was:

> **Guru**: Looking at all your orders you won't be able to
>   differentiate. When you click through to a singular order though,
>   you'll be able to see in its timeline that it came from Amazon instead
>   of your Online store.
>
> **My team**:  mmm so if I connect though the API
>   "orders.json?id=xxxx" the only way I can check it came from amazon is
>   though the timeline?
>
> **Guru**:  As far as I'm aware that's the case. I can check with our
>   development team to see if there's another indicator. Would I be able
>   to email you back with any additional findings?

Of course my team is still waiting on an answer from them but I bet someone at SO has already been in this situation before.

Some might want to know why I need to know the order source. We are sending these orders from Shopify into Netsuite via a Celigo connector. Amazon orders need to hit a different GL account than the normal Shopify orders and my task is to code the correct mapping based on some differentiating element or name/value pair from the JSON response.

Comment: Why not search for that order in Amazon using Amazon MWS API

Comment: Have you checked the `source_name` to see when Amazon sends the order it changes this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an order comes down the JSON has a field called `source_name` and the value should be something like this: `sell-on-amazon`

`"source_name":"sell-on-amazon"`